# What comes before precalculus

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I studied in Europe and followed mostly European academic ways. I'm tutoring a young person , and I will to know what math class comes before pre calculus. Because soon we will be starting some precalculus exercises

Comment: @Downvoter I think this is a totally reasonable question. As a person from Europe myself, terms such as precalculus and algebra were seldom used, and I didn't know about them before I started reading mathematics from English sources.

Comment: I don't understand either the downvote or the close votes; this is a very reasonable question.

Answer (score 5):

In the United States, the sequence is usually elementary algebra (Algebra I), Euclidean geometry (Geometry), intermediate algebra (Algebra II), then a course on the properties of functions that includes analytic trigonometry (Pre-calculus/Advanced Algebra and Trigonometry).

Comment: In that case is it safe to say that "advanced Algebra & trig are the equivalent of precalculus?"

Comment: Advanced Algebra and Trigonometry is sometimes used as another name for Pre-Calculus.  However, at some schools, weaker students may take an "Advanced" Algebra course, then take a Pre-calculus course.  It can sometimes be a nice way of saying the student is weak in mathematics without explicitly indicating that the student is in a basic level class.

Comment: @christian: Approximately. The student may have seen a little basic trigonometry, but if so, probably only the definitions of the trig functions in terms of a right triangle. The laws of exponents will probably need a review, and logarithms will probably largely unexplored territory.

Comment: Not only that, @BrianM.Scott. I think most students in USA finish high school without even studying derivatives, integrals, complex numbers, basic probability and stuff, though this may vary from state  state, and perhaps even different schools in the same state. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Timbuc: Nowadays a great many have had some calculus. Some will have had a minimal exposure to complex numbers. Basic probability is still very uncommon, though. And yes, there is less uniformity than is common in most other educational systems with which I have any familiarity at all.